# How do I compress multiple files into a single archive with Delphi

Tags: delphi, compression

I need to compress multiple files into a single archive using Delphi. I'd prefer to use freeware components or open-source components because I am very very cheap :-)

My primary requirements are:

1. Possible to encrypt the archive
2. Can create common archives that can be opened by anyone with a copy of WinZip

Does anyone have suggestions with components that they have used? Please feel free to suggest free as well as commercial components/libraries.

Comment: Have you looked at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74519/using-7zip-from-delphi)?

Comment: I've considered that method, but the answers focus primarily on 7-zip type solutions. I'm also looking for some comments anyone has with their experience using these tools.

Comment: The advantage of 7-zip is that it works really, really well on any ZIP you ever throw at it. Other components tend to work mostly OK for *most* ZIPs.

Comment: one other advantage is 7-zip does a better job of compressing the file - The 7z files are at least 30% smaller than a the zip file

Comment: What is the Delphi version?

Comment: Plus 1 for being "very very cheap"!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps [DelphiZip](http://www.delphizip.org/) is what you are looking for, it seems to support encryption, too, and is WinZip compatible. It is released under LGPL.

Comment: DelphiZip requires separate DLLs

Answer (score 4):

[KaZip](http://www.vclcomponents.com/Delphi/Compression__Encryption/KAZip-info.html) is an open-source ZIP archiver. Here is its description:

> KAZIP is fast, simple ZIP archiver and
>   dearchiver which uses most popular ZIP
>   format.Inflate - Deflate zip
>   compression format (no encryption
>   support and no multidisk
>   support).KAZip is totaly based on
>   Delphi VCL - **no DLL, ActiveX or other
>   external libraries**.KAZip is totaly
>   stream oriented so you can deal with
>   data only in memory without creating
>   temporary files, etc. If you need to
>   add zip-unzip functionality to your
>   application,KAZIP is the right
>   solution. Additional ZipListView and
>   ZipTreeView components for easy
>   visualisation.Functionality:Zip-Unzip
>   using Inflate-DeflateBZip2 unzipping
>   trough usage of BZIP2 units from
>   Edison Mera Menndez.Functions:Adding
>   Files, Folders, Streams; Selecting,
>   Deselecting, Checking;Extracting to
>   files and streams;Delete and Rename
>   filesCreate, Delete and Rename
>   foldersTest, RepairMany new properties
>   and methods, improved speed.A very
>   complex Zip Browser demo application
>   is included

It is not compatible with Delphi 2009 yet, but with some minor changes in the source code, you can make it work in Delphi 2009 too. Actually, that's what I did.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the $69 [ZipForge](http://www.componentace.com/zip_component_zip_delphi_zipforge.htm) from ComponentAce.

Answer (score 3):

I`m using [madZip](http://help.madshi.net/madZipUnit.htm#Zip) from [madCollection](http://www.madshi.net)

Comment: I wasn't even aware of this one. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no-one has mentioned JclCompression yet - it's part of the well-known Jedi Code Library (JCL).
Here's a view of the unit itself : http://jcl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jcl/trunk/jcl/source/common/JclCompression.pas?view=markup

Note, it's compatible with 7-zip DLL version 4.64 - newer versions might not be backwards-compatible...

Answer (score 2):

You could use 7zip (LZMA) bindings for Pascal (compatible with Delphi): http://www.birtles.org.uk/programming/

Answer (score 2):

Another Delphi resource to look at would be [InnoSetup](http://www.innosetup.com/isdl.php).  The source code is available and with a little work might give you an edge up on what your trying to do.  There is an option to create self extracting zip archives which are compatible with WinZip,

My thoughts are not to use the program, but to use his source as a starting point since it is very heavily tested and extremely solid.

Answer (score 1):

There are [infozips](http://www.info-zip.org/) zip32 and unzip32 dlls. They can be used from Delphi (even from Visual Basic), there are interface units/modules for both. The interface isn't as good as I would have liked it, but it works.