# Third party component for zip file(s)/folder(s)

Tags: delphi, zip, delphi-xe2

Someone knows a third party component that allows to visually manage zip file(s) / folder(s)? For example as is in WinZip application (es: add, delete new file in zipfile etc)?

Comment: Again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442047/delphi-compression-component

Comment: @Andreas, why didn't you vote to close as a dupe?

Comment: @andreas, i have saw about this product too, and are all very good, but not give nothing info about screenshot. For all that i need to do, any product listed is good, but i need of that product that has a good vcl, as in winzip program; some screenshot where i can find?

Comment: @Johan: I wasn't 100 % sure it was a dupe. The other question is about a compression library. I almost got the feeling that Marcello wants a tool with its own GUI included.

Comment: Yes, if there is of course. I can to do it too, but if there is something of ready and extetically good, then i prefer use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Sample application showing TAbTreeView and TAbListView][Abbrevia](http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia) 5.0 has a new set of components, `TAbListView` and `TAbTreeView` that work together to give a view very similar to WinZip's or Explorer.  You can make them reference each other and one of the archiver components (e.g., `TAbZipKit`) and they'll automatically pull out the folder structure to show in the treeview and show the files in the selected folder in the listview.  The listview also supports the flat "all files" view without the treeview.

The screenshot above is from the **ComCtrlsDemo** project in the Delphi examples directory, and the only code in it is to support extracting the content to the memo, and to change the view styles.

They are read-only though.  To add files you work with the archive component directly (`TAbZipKit.AddFiles()`), and if you wanted to support drag & drop into/out of Explorer you would need to do that yourself.  Anders Melander's [Drag and Drop Component Suite](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop) would be a good start for that.

Answer (score 4):

VCLZip is one. There are several others.  http://vclzip.bizland.com/

Answer (score 3):

[TurboPower Abbrevia](http://tpabbrevia.sourceforge.net/) has forms to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is ZipForge by Component Ace. [Link](http://componentace.com/zip_component_zip_delphi_zipforge.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged the question with "Delphi XE" tag. 
The new version of Delphi have native support for ZIP Files.

See this blog article: [Testeando XE2… (soporte nativo para ficheros ZIP)](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/?p=1752) ([authomatic translation with google trans.](http://tinyurl.com/3ogmz62))

You can find also, the code of sample for add, create, extract,...

Regards.

Comment: That's what I thought too (and answered), but question asks for visual components for ZIP files. Slightly different.

Comment: @David Heffernan. Thanks David. You're on right. I have missed this detail.