# how to get the 7z archive's item stream?

Tags: delphi

i use the jedi 's  jcl  TJclDecompressArchiveClass and TJclDecompressArchive

//http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/index.php?title=JEDI_Code_Library

```
var
  archiveclass: TJclDecompressArchiveClass;
  archive: TJclDecompressArchive;
  item: TJclCompressionItem;

implementation
  uses JclCompression;

archiveclass := GetArchiveFormats.FindDecompressFormat('c:\1.7z'));
  archive := archiveclass.Create('c:\1.7z');
  archive.ListFiles;
  archive.OnProgress := Form1.ArchiveProgress;


  for i := 0 to archive.ItemCount - 1 do
    begin
      item := archive.Items[i];
      try
      case item.Kind of
        ikFile:
         begin
         item.Selected:=True;
         archive.ExtractSelected('e:\temp');
// how to get the archive.item[i].Selected.stream ?





      end;

    end;
    finally


      end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this question: [Using 7-Zip from Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74519/using-7-zip-from-delphi)

Comment: yes,i saw that question,but that question can not get the archive.item[i].Selected.stream, thank you