# How can I use jclcompression in Delphi, is there any example?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I installed jclcompressin component yesterday. When I use it there is an error "load to 7z.dll".
Has anyone example code using the jclcompressıon unit? As if I compress a text file?

Answer (score 9):

In order to work with the `JclCompression` unit you must have the `7z.dll` file in the same path where your exe is located. you can get this file downloding the 7zip installer from [here](http://www.7-zip.org/) (**remember always use 32-bit x86 version of the dll**).

for samples about using this unit you can check the project located in this folder

`<Path to your JCL library>\jcl\examples\windows\compression\archive`

or  you can check this question

[`Using 7-Zip from Delphi?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74519/using-7-zip-from-delphi)

Comment: Hello RRUZ! I did what your answer said. But when i execute the project example the software return: "Cannot load sevenzip library". I just put the 7z.dll in the example folder. Do you have any idea about this problem? Thanks for help!

Comment: Just debug the [sevenzip](https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl/blob/master/jcl/source/windows/sevenzip.pas) unit and check why the code fails to load the dll.