# How to compress a Folder uses lzma sdk?

Tags: c++, delphi, 7zip, lzma

http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html
I can uses it compress a file, but can not find function of compress a Folder

Comment: Which version of Delphi? Would you consider ZIP which was added in XE?

Comment: 7z  compression ratio bigger  than ZIP and rar

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create a `.7z` archive, then include all files of the folder within. There is no direct "folder" compression: just compression of files. If you store a (relative) folder name within the file name (e.g. 'FolderName\FileName'), the folder 'FolderName' will appear within the archive.

You have within the SDK a ANSI-C compatible source code for 7z decompression with example.
You'll have to adapt it to add all files of the folder to the archive (using `FindFirst / FindNext / FindClose` and recursion if you want the sub-folder to be included).

*Edit:* In fact, there is no .7z writing in the sdk. Only opening/extraction from a .7z archive within the sdk. You'll have to code it by hand... So perhaps the [Using 7-Zip from Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74519/using-7-zip-from-delphi) answer will help you here.

Comment: Does 7 zip not have archive/directory features?

Comment: lzma sdk  not have archive/directory features

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In the SDK, you have two levels: 1. lzma compression (over stream or buffer); 2. .7z archive format. The .7z archive format does handle archive/directory features.