# Does 7Zip SDK support also the container?

Tags: 7zip, lzma

I am doing a some research on `7Zip SDK` and I haven't find any info about the container. Does `7Zip SDK` have the `LZMA` algorithm only or does it support also the `7Zip container`?

`Zip`, for example, keeps the directory structure at the end of the file, is `7Zip` doing the same or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [How to compress a Folder uses lzma sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260241/how-to-compres-a-folder-uses-lzma-sdk) in the 7zip SDK, we have two levels:

- `LZMA compression` - (over stream or buffer);
- `.7z archive format` - The `.7z` archive format does handle archive/directory features.

Found a very good `7zip C++ wrapper` on https://bitbucket.org/cmcnab/sevenzip which is a very good example and works great!